# RCharts - Choosing color by category column chart

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, rcharts

I have a RCharts question (more generally an highchart demand).
I am trying to build a column chart with 2 categories and 2 bars for each category, it's quite simple.

But I can't display colors I want. By default, each bar has the same color is each category, but I would like that each bar in one category have the same color. I can't do it.

My R code below :

```
col_chart <- Highcharts$new()
col_chart$xAxis(categories=list('A', 'B') ) 
col_chart$series(list(list(type="column",
                             name="1",data=c(6,7))
                        ,list(type="column",
                              name="2",data=c(1,3))
                         ))
```

As everyone likes there, this is a very minimal reproductible example. There, each modality "1" is blue and each modality "2" is dark. I would like to make a difference between A and B, not between 1 and 2.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution.**

It is possibile to specify the color of each bar using the `colors` and `colorByPoint` options:

```
library(rCharts)
col_chart <- Highcharts$new()
col_chart$xAxis(categories=list('A', 'B') ) 
col_chart$series(list(
    list(type="column", name="1",data=c(6,7), 
         colors=list('#7cb5ec', '#FF0000'), colorByPoint=TRUE),
    list(type="column", name="2",data=c(1,3), 
         colors=list('#7cb5ec', '#FF0000'), colorByPoint=TRUE)
))
col_chart
```

[image]

**Second solution.**

```
col_chart <- Highcharts$new()
col_chart$xAxis(categories=list('A', 'B') ) 
col_chart$series(list(
    list(type="column", name="1", 
         data=list(list(color='#7cb5ec',y=6),list(color='#FF0000',y=7))
    ),
    list(type="column", name="2", 
         data=list(list(color='#7cb5ec',y=1),list(color='#FF0000',y=3))
    )
))
col_chart
```

[image]

Comment: That works very well. I thought I tried this, but no, I put the 'colorByPoint=TRUE' in plotOptions parameters, not directly in the series. Thank you.